# Using AJAX to check variables in database, if true, header to a certain page, PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to check variables in the database, and if it's true, then it should make it header to a certain page, except in this testing phrase, I'm not checking any variables. I'm just testing if it'll header off to that certain page if I call the function. I started at test1.php, but it should've called the ajax function, and immediately header off to test3.php, but it didn't. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look:

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function nopassAjax(url,timeout) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             setTimeout(function() { timeoutAjax(url,timeout); }, timeout);
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

> test1.php

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<script>";

echo "nopassAjax('test2.php',1000);";

echo "</script>";

?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php

//checks some stuff in the database
//if true, header off to test3.php

header("Location: test3.php");

?>
```

> test3.php

```
<?php

echo "Hello";

?>
```

Comment: Firstly, it should be `header('Location: test3.php');` to redirect, and secondly, sending a header like that in an ajax request doesn't redirect the calling page, that simply can't be done with PHP, but has to be done in javascript when the ajax call returns something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm assuming you want to redirect to the page that's returned from your AJAX call. You can't do this from PHP alone.
Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: someUrl
}).fail( function( error ) {
    alert( error );
}).done( function( response ) {
    window.location = response;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
     echo "test3.php";
?>
```

Comment: window.location should be equal to test3.php, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, where is it checking the stuff in the database before heading to test3.php?